# flutter web using InAppWebView not getting result as expected

Tags: android, ios, flutter

i am trying to implement payments in flutter web previously implemented on mobile android/ios and it is working fine on them but when implementing it on web getting unexpected error from razor pay that  POST **https://lumberjack-cx.stage.razorpay.in/beacon/v1/batch?writeKey=503 (Service Unavailable)**
why its showing Unavailable and they transaction is showing successfully but not getting in wallet my code is

```
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(56),
    child: CommonAppBar(
      title: 'Payment Information',
    ),
  ),
  body: Container(
    child: InAppWebView(
      initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: WebUri(widget.url)),
      initialSettings: InAppWebViewSettings(
          cacheEnabled: true,
          javaScriptEnabled: true,
          javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically: true,
          useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
          useShouldInterceptRequest: true),
      onReceivedError: (controller, request, error) {
        log('error: ${error.toString()}');
      },
      onLoadResource: (controller, resource) {
        log('onLoadResource : ${resource}');
      },
      onLoadStart: (controller, url) {
        log('start url: ${url.toString()}');
      },
      onReceivedHttpError: (controller, request, error) {
        log('http error: ${error.toString()} and req is $request');
      },
      onLoadStop: (controller, url) {
        log('onLoadStop called: ${url.toString()}');

        if (url
            .toString()
            .startsWith("https://astroway.diploy.in/payment-success")) {
          Get.off(() => BottomNavigationBarScreen(index: 0));
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Payment Success!",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Get.theme.primaryColor,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 14.0,
          );
        } else if (url
            .toString()
            .startsWith("https://astroway.diploy.in/payment-failed")) {
          Get.off(() => BottomNavigationBarScreen(index: 0));
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Payment Failed!",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
            backgroundColor: Get.theme.primaryColor,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 14.0,
          );
        }
      },
      onWebViewCreated: (webviewcontroller) {
        _controller = webviewcontroller;

        log('onWebViewCreated: }');

        kIsWeb
            ? {}
            : _controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
                handlerName: 'PaymentSuccess',
                callback: (args) {
                  log('loaded PaymentSuccess: ${args.toString()}');

                  Get.off(() => BottomNavigationBarScreen(index: 0));
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: "Payment Success!",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Get.theme.primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  );
                },
              );
        kIsWeb
            ? {}
            : _controller.addJavaScriptHandler(
                handlerName: 'PaymentFailed',
                callback: (args) {
                  log('loaded PaymentFailed: ${args.toString()}');

                  Get.off(() => BottomNavigationBarScreen(index: 0));
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(
                    msg: "Payment Failed!",
                    toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                    gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                    timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Get.theme.primaryColor,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                  );
                },
              );
      },
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

The issue is that the code is not entering the onLoadStop callback of the InAppWebView widget, but the payment success screen is still being displayed. any help much appreciated

[image: screen]